# Unreachable gitlab page with custom domain

Tags: dns, gitlab, hosting, hugo

I created a site with Hugo and I hosted it as a gitlab page.

To assign my custom domain I followed the instructions of [this document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/) of gitlab.

I created three DNS records:

1. one of type `A` with name `@` and value `35.185.44.232`;
2. one of type `TXT` with name `@` and value `_gitlab-pages-verification ...` for the verification of the ownership of the domain;
3. one of type `A` with name `www` and value `35.185.44.232`.

If I access the site using the address `https://example.com` everything works normally; but if I log in using the triple W (`www.example.com`) I get from gitlab the error message `401 You don't have permission to access the resource. The resource that you are attempting to access is protected and you don't have the necessary permissions to view it.`

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Try a `CNAME` instead of a second `A` record for your `WWW.` subdomain. Having two `A` records - one that points to your naked domain and one that points to your WWW-domain is either causing redirect error or simply does not exist since it, as your origin's subdomain, must exist as a separate entity on GitLab *OR* you can not concern yourself with it by using a `CNAME` record as I previously recommended and using a directory-style (as opposed to a subdomain-style) setup for your site. Each has its own benefits as well as drawbacks. I use the `CNAME` method *and* have a WWW-subdomain setup on GitLab in order for my sites to grant that extra bit of security and privacy to visitors that having a TLS cert installed on the `WWW-subdomain` offers.

Comment: Please, can you explain as precisely as you can how to setup a _directory style_?

Comment: _Absolutely_! A multi directory layout would initially contain your /public dir. and your main index.html. Further directories would be added as such, including each directory's index.html which will translate to whatever you name that directory: /public/dir/index.html /public/dir2/index.html /public/dir3/index.html etc

Comment: Some simple examples may be seen here: `https://gitlab.com/iosprivacy` esp. in `https://gitlab.com/iosprivacy/cdn`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how to setup my gitlab page with "directory style" in order to obtain the reachability of the site with the address equipped with the initial `www`. Please give me a precise and "step by step" explanation. Note that gitlab automatically manages static sites built with Hugo and the "`public`" directory is not easily accessible.

Comment: The `public` directory is accessible within Hugo. In fact, as the *creator of the site* you *control its design*. It all starts with your `config.toml` file. In it, at its very beginning, define the following so that Hugo uses the specified directories in your site's repo:
`baseurl = "https://example.com"
contentdir    = "content"
layoutdir     = "layouts"
publishdir    = "public"` Now, within your repo, the directory `layouts` hold the config files which structure your site. Before we continue, I have to ask why you've chosen Hugo? It would seem using static HTML would be simpler for you.

Comment: Just to note, I recommend static HTML, despite the fact that you've already (apparently) built and deployed a (mostly) working site via Hugo for these reasons: 1) you'll not encounter the frustration you have been using Hugo. Now, not knowing why you've chosen a framework (read: something that gets in between you and your site), despite the claims made by its devs, Hugo may be specifically what you believe you "need". 2) Expanding on `1)`, you, using so-called "static" HTML can design anything (within the limits of technology) you want as a site.